# How can I use DOM xpath to get the href out of a variable in php?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Thanks for helping!

I am trying to figure out how to extract the href attribute out of a php variable that contains a single tag... Like so

```
$var = "<a class='coupon_link' href='http://www.anrdoezrs.net/r365wktqks7EDD8BDB799AACCEE' target='_blank' onmouseover='window.status=' http:='' www.myjewelrybox.com';return='' true;'='' onmouseout='window.status=' ';return=''><img src='http://www.lduhtrp.net/fl115vvzntrCJIIDGIGCEEFFHHJJ' alt='' border='0'></a>";
```

I have heard that you can do this with xpath somehow but have been unsuccessful in my attempts :-/

Here is what I was trying:

```
  $xml  = simplexml_load_string($var);
  $myhref = $xml->xpath("//a[contains(@href,'foo')]");

  echo $myhref;
```

Thanks again!

Comment: The string you've provided as `$var` isn't valid XML.  When I try to load that string into SimpleXML, I get about three page fulls of warning messages.  If you aren't seeing anything, you're going to want to check your `error_reporting` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Charles comment, I suggest using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) when parsing random HTML

```
$var = "<a class='coupon_link' href='http://www.anrdoezrs.net/r365wktqks7EDD8BDB799AACCEE/foo' target='_blank' onmouseover='window.status=' http:='' www.myjewelrybox.com';return='' true;'='' onmouseout='window.status=' ';return=''><img src='http://www.lduhtrp.net/fl115vvzntrCJIIDGIGCEEFFHHJJ' alt='' border='0'></a>";

$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
@$xml->loadHTML($var);
$oXpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$inputs = $oXpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'foo')]");
var_dump($inputs);
```